# Calling $setValidity inside $formatters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive used with `select`. It makes sure that selected object which is bound to `select` has a property.

```
bxUi.directive('bxHasOwnProperty', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

            function validate(viewValue) {
                var prop = attrs.bxHasOwnProperty;
                if (viewValue && prop && viewValue[prop] && viewValue[prop] !== "") {
                    modelCtrl.$setValidity('required', true);
                } else {
                    modelCtrl.$setValidity('required', false);
                }

                return viewValue;
            }

            modelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(validate);
            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(validate);
        }
    };
});
```

Sample usage would be :

`<select name="city" ng-model="city" ng-options="c.name for c in vm.cities" bx-has-own-property="name"></select>`

So as a result, if user selects city without name, `required` validation will fail.

What I'm not sure I did correctly is that parser & validator are using the same implementation, in particular that `$setValidity` is used in both. It works but I'm not sure this is correct. I was thinking about complete removal of `modelCtrl.$formatters.push(validate);`, but when I did it, there is a side effect. If I manuall set the model in controller to city with no name (e.g. `{}`), `required` validator is not set and I don't see UI feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `$setValidity` within `$parsers/$formatters`. However, in most cases it should be sufficient to use the `modelCtrl.$validators` and `modelCtrl.$asyncValidators` collections which will call `$setValidity` automatically.

Try this one:

```
bxUi.directive('bxHasOwnProperty', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$validators.required = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                var prop = attrs.bxHasOwnProperty;
                return (viewValue && prop && viewValue[prop] && viewValue[prop] !== "");
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thx, this code is still used by some Angular 1.2 apps, thus I cannot use $validators :/